# How to put all social media buttons on one line

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have written HTML code for my website to display social media buttons. Here is my code.

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/manulimanawadu/">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTofwQKKw9lPFjwjnV0tCtz9575RJYAieEtUKop8H3fmU-uWRNetA" alt="submit to reddit" width="30" height="30" border="0"></a><a href="https://www.facebook.com/manulipiyalka.manawadu">
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yootheme/social-bookmark/256/social-facebook-box-blue-icon.png" alt="submit to reddit" width="30" height="30" border="0"></a><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/5808332/manuli-piyalka">
<img class="alignnone" src="https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.423192949.8659/mp,550x550,matte,ffffff,t.3u1.jpg" alt="submit to reddit" width="30" height="30" border="0"></a><a href="https://plus.google.com/u/1/?tab=mX">
<img class="alignnone" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQenywtsd-Mnhvg8VOhvU4wxruIn3zjvPKz69gafQQVS-e9fGUc" alt="submit to reddit" width="28" height="26" border="0"></a><a href="https://twitter.com/piyalka">
<img class="alignnone" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTiVU8-w06xNJCCOPoOwfugQUHhuyFoqYs0YsxZ9zgXkVrcXDtU" alt="submit to reddit" width="24" height="24" border="0"></a>
```

In this case my social media buttons are not appearing in one line.

[image: oic]

How could I put all the buttons into one line?

best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `img` elements are inline and would appear in one line with the provided code. There must be some CSS rule in your WP theme which either makes them block elements (by applying `display: block`) or floats and clears them at the same time (`float: left; clear: left`). So you have to find out which of these settings apply and overwrite them with a CSS rule.

You could for example add a self-defined class to each `img` element which contains something like:

```
.my_sm_buttons {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  clear: none;
}
```

And in your HTML you would remove the `alignnone` classes and add `class="my_sm_buttons"` in each `img` tag. So the first `img` tag for example would look like

```
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTofwQKKw9lPFjwjnV0tCtz9575RJYAieEtUKop8H3fmU-uWRNetA" alt="submit to reddit" width="30" height="30" border="0" class="my_sm_buttons">
```

That might be a bit too much (i.e. the inline-block *and* float reset), but it should work. If it doesn't, you could still add `!important` to each of those settings, like

```
.my_sm_buttons {
  display: inline-block !important;
  float: none !important;
  clear: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Can I do it only using HTML?

Comment: Well, you can put those CSS settings into your HTML tags, as `style` attributes. For example `<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTofwQKKw9lPFjwjnV0tCtz9575RJYAieEtUKop8H3fmU-uWRNetA" alt="submit to reddit" width="30" height="30" border="0" style="display: inline-block; float:none; clear:none">` or similar

Answer (score 0):

You need to use css to float left:

```
<div class="social-icons">
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/manulimanawadu/">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTofwQKKw9lPFjwjnV0tCtz9575RJYAieEtUKop8H3fmU-uWRNetA" alt="submit to reddit" width="30" height="30" border="0"></a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/manulimanawadu/">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTofwQKKw9lPFjwjnV0tCtz9575RJYAieEtUKop8H3fmU-uWRNetA" alt="submit to reddit" width="30" height="30" border="0"></a>
</div>


<style type="text/css">
    .social-icons img{
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```